# Backups on a network don't work in a daily job

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, backup

We are using virtual machine. On these machines, we have a job every night that makes backups of our databases, a backup on the computer and a backup on our backup network. We often have problems with network backups that always occur on the same databases. We must have about ten databases and it always happens on the same one. 
Here is the code of the backup:

Step 1

```
BACKUP DATABASE [REFERENTIEL_TRACK] TO DISK = N'\ECWP-FCM\Backups\MIS-VDB02\REFERENTIEL_TRACK.bak' WITH COMPRESSION, NOFORMAT, INIT, NAME = N'REFERENTIEL_TRACK-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10
GO
```

Step 2

```
declare @backupSetId as int
select @backupSetId = position from msdb..backupset where database_name=N'REFERENTIEL_TRACK' and backup_set_id=(select max(backup_set_id) from msdb..backupset where database_name=N'REFERENTIEL_TRACK' )
if @backupSetId is null begin raiserror(N'Verify failed. Backup information for database ''REFERENTIAL_TRACK'' not found.', 16, 1) end
RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = N'\ECWP-FCM\Backups\MIS-VDB02\REFERENTIAL_TRACK.bak' WITH FILE = @backupSetId, NOUNLOAD, NOREWIND
GO
```

We have 2 types of error messages :

-Most often the error occurs in step 1 and you have

```
The backup data at the end of 'devicename' is incorrectly formatted. Backup sets on the media might be damaged and unusable. To determine the backup sets on the media, use RESTORE HEADERONLY. To determine the usability of the backup sets, run RESTORE VERIFYONLY. If all of the backup sets are incomplete, reformat the media using BACKUP WITH FORMAT, which destroys all the backup sets.
Server: Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

-Sometimes in step 2 and you get

```
VERIFY DATABASE is terminating abnormally. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 3013).  The step failed.
```

We have tried to change the time of the job and change the order of the steps in the job, but we still have these error. We also tried to make the backup on another network, same error.

We restored one of the backups made on the computer and for 15 days we had no more problems, but we had problems again. We tried to restore again a backup made on the computer, but after 2 days we had again errors at the first stage.

Reading the first error message and after some research we changed the code to make a backup with format.

```
BACKUP DATABASE [REFERENTIEL_TRACK] TO DISK = N'\ECWP-FCM\Backups\MIS-VDB02\REFERENTIEL_TRACK.bak' WITH COMPRESSION, FORMAT, INIT, NAME = N'REFERENTIEL_TRACK-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10
GO
```

We have less error but sometimes we still get the error in step 2.

```
VERIFY DATABASE is terminating abnormally. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 3013).  The step failed.
```

We've read on forums that these kinds of errors can happen because of network cuts, but then why do we only have the problem on the same base?

Do you have any other ideas where these errors can come from and how to solve it?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you try to achieve on network drive ? we generally do local backup at x time and x+1 hour local backup will be zipped and transferred to network drive and local backup gets deleted.

Comment: That's the process we decided to put in place. Why does a network backup not work as well as a local backup?

Comment: because network drive writing access, network fluctuation, AD/Non AD server are some impacts to network backup. you can read more from : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/backup-devices-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#NetworkShare but It is generally a good practice to have local backup and move to network later if you are not using any NAS techniques.

Comment: and practically we faced issues that take backup in local and move .bak file to remote drive and while restoring it gives error backup file corrupted. after spending days we could found that some .bak files corrupted while transmitting in network. so we shifted from .bak to .zip conversion and move .zip file to network drive